# (REST ) Client - set the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest into request How to?

Tags: http, jersey, client, httpclient

A lot of web applications must be used the specified REST service. This REST service uses currently the informations only from *javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest*. This HttpServletRequest may be contain the specific cookie and other parameters.

I'm try to use the (REST) client API form JERSEY to realize a client, that will build the REST requests. This client will be called within custom web filter, that will be registered by web.xml of each web application.

Currently i have the following problem: i'm don't know, howto transmitt the HttpServletRequest during call of the REST Service....

Thx for your help....

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want receive a `request` in any of the web applications, and then you want to forward this `request` to the REST web service?

If so, you will need to serialize the request to make it transportable. You could also create a class that is able to hold the data that you need from the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` and then serialize it into XML or JSON.

If you have the `request` in a more transportable format, you can pass it to your REST service via a [@HeaderParam](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.8/jersey/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) or as the request body (I would prefer the latter).